# Access_token CNN News Post from their page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token

How to obtain an access_token for CNN? 
CNN won't be using the App I create.

Or 
How do I *filter* and read CNN Posts from one of my own INTERESTS list in json.

Websites like CNN and Gizmag do have RSS Feeds for their Posts & done that.

Answer (score 0):

To read CNN's feed, you need any valid access token. It can be an App access token. The page owner does not have to install your app.

You can get their feed at `https://graph.facebook.com/CNN/feed?access_token=XXXX`

Create your app, and follow [these instructions to get an app access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/) or use one of the Facebook SDK's and it will get a token from you App Id when you initialize the SDK.

The only exception to this is if your page has age or country restrictions. Then you need a user access token for someone who meets the page owner's criteria. This will not work if you try to look at the Maker's Mark (MakersMark) page.